# Redirecting Magento to domain root from sub-folder 500 error

Tags: magento-1.9, setup, domain

My magento site is stored in a sub-folder of my root domain **mydomain.com/magento** - I am trying to get the site working at mydomain.com (leaving admin available at **mydomain.com/magento/admin**).

I have updated the base url `store view` in admin panel to mydomain.com/ as suggested in [another post on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749733/how-to-direct-magento-installation-path-in-subfolder-to-main-domain-name). I have also copied the index.php to the root folder and updated this line (47):

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/magento/app/Mage.php';
```

I have only updated the line in the index.php located in root - not the one located in the /magento/ folder.

Unfortunately, something has gone wrong as when I visit the site via **mydomain.com/** I get a 500 error. The site is still accessible via `mydomain.com/magento` and the admin is also fine.

Can anyone please suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

In 1.9 this was resolved by adding /magento/ to every directory reference in the index.php file, line 42-65 (see detail below).

```
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/magento/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/magento/app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/magento/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}

require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/magento/app/bootstrap.php';
```